# Does RegisterRoutes method will reduce performance?

Tags: asp.net, routes

I use `RegisterRoutes` method in Global.asax as below:

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("", "en-us/Articles/Browse", "~/en_us/Articles/Default.aspx");
    }
```

so, I have many pages that I did the same for them (106 aspx pages). Did this work will affect performance?

and secend question is: Is there a way to summarize `routes.MapPageRoute` for a webApp with many pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't any page loads since the routes are registered at the startup of the application. Granted there will be a larger dictionary to test against, but I think you're talking about milliseconds of difference.

As for summarizing things. I don't see any way to do it with the example URL you posted. If you had some standard URL scheme that mapped the routed URL to a page in a standard scheme, you could probably do it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When you say 'milliseconds', do you mean that the effect is too small?

Comment: @Mar_a You maybe able yo measure it, but I doubt it would be noticeable to any human.